# Como remover essa quebra de linha?

Tags: php, javascript, quebras-de-linha

tenho uma pagina que usa um editor de texto do tipo 'wysiwyg' que no caso é um elemento textarea, esse gera um codigo html pro texto que o usuario digitar, eu salvo o valor deste campo no onblur do mesmo atraves de um ajax que faz salvar no SESSION via php, o problema está depois, quero fazer com que esse texto que o usuario digitou apareça na tela (mesmo que o usuario atualize a pagina), e estou com problema de setar o texto no editor de texto, pois o codigo gerado é gerado com quebra de linha, e ao colocar esse valor no javascript dá erro devido a essa quebra de linha ja procurei maneiras de remover essas quebras de linha, mas n achei uma que funcionasse.

função que chama ajax:

```
function SalvaSession(valor){
      $.post( "ajax_salva_session.php",
            {
                'texto' : valor  //valor recebe o html do editor de texto
           },
           function (data) {
           }
      );
 }
```

arquivo ajax_salva_session.php (que salva o texto recebido do editor):

```
<?php
    $texto = isset($_POST['texto']) ? $_POST['texto'] : '';
    $texto = str_replace("\n", " ", $texto); //usei essas 3 formas que achei  
    $texto = str_replace("\r", " ", $texto); //na net pra tentar eliminar a quebra
    $texto = preg_replace('/\s/',' ',$texto);//de linha, mas até o momento sem sucesso :/
    $_SESSION['capitulo'] = $texto;
?>
```

linha que seta o texto no editor de texto (a sintaxe está certa, é a sintaxe que consta na documentação: $("#placeHolder").Editor("setText", "Text")):

```
$('#paragrafo').Editor('setText', "<?php echo ($_SESSION['capitulo']); ?>");
```

texto gerado no browser (que dá erro):

```
$('#paragrafo').Editor('setText', "<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line <i>10</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0058</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>241440</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
");
```

Comment: Duas coisas: você está usando `session_start();` no começo do seu código? E isso aqui está errado: `<?php echo ($_SESSION['capitulo']); ?>`. No mínimo precisa de `<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['capitulo']); ?>`, senão qualquer ocorrência de aspas vai te causar problema.

Comment: nossa, não tava usando, agora coloquei os dois, o session_start foi por desatenção mesmo, mas não sabia desse htmlentities, agora vo ve se acho o erro, que ainda persiste.

Comment: Alexandre, tire suas remoções de quebra de linha com str_replace, e use só isso: `<?php echo nl2br( htmlentities( $_SESSION['capitulo'] ) ); ?>`, dependendo do editor pode funcionar.

Comment: eu ouvi falar desse nl2br, mas acho q n vo poder usar, pq a quebra de linha q ocorre do javascript n é uma quebra de linha da formatação do html, e somente a forma que o editor cria o  html

Comment: Bom, de fato o nl2br nao remove as quebras, seria o caso de primeiro aplicar o nl2br, e depois o replace

Comment: mas então pra que eu usaria o nl2br, se minha intenção n é criar br? e sim REMOVER as quebras de linha?

Comment: Sua intenção é remover a quebra pq ela está dando problema. Eu já pensei em resolver só o problema, respeitando o texto original (ou seja, fazer funcionar com a quebra). Mas sem conhecer o componente que vc está usando, tudo é chute. É o tipo da coisa que deve ser só alguma bobeirinha atrapalhando, mas que fica complicado entender a situação sem examinar de perto.

Comment: o componente q to usando é o line control editor, o link dele é esse https://github.com/suyati/line-control/blob/master/README.md

Comment: tem alguma forma de fazer funcionar com essas quebras de linha no javascript? porque o php na vdd ta jogando o erro de session no html que seria setado no editor q uso..

Comment: mas n estou entendendo porque está dando erro na variavel do meu session, sendo que eu ja coloquei nos dois arquivos q usam sessão o session_start();  e defini a sessao $_SESSION['capitulo'] = $texto

Comment: Por isso que eu fiz meu 1o comentario. enquanto nao arrumar o erro, nao tá testando nada. Só que não dá pra gente aqui saber qual é sua linha 10 , que tem o problema. Pode ser um $ faltando, ou algum ; errado, etc. Se puder comentar o que tem na sua linha 10, talvez ajude.

Comment: consegui remover a quebra de linha enfim! obrigado por toda a ajud, suas dicas ajudaram, acho que o problema maior foi eu n ter declarado o session_start() no inicio e ele ter salvo no session o codigo de erro do php, e daí dava erro o tempo todo, agora mudei o que está armazenado no session e consegui resolver pelo esse erro, mto obrigado pelas dicas @Bacco!

Comment: Se conseguiste resolver o problema aceita a resposta que ajudou ou coloca uma resposta nova se a solução não estiver nas respostas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente dar um *replace* assim:

```
str_replace("> <", "><", $texto);
```

Caso isso não funcione o problema pode ser com as aspas. Tem um `colspan="5"`, com aspas duplas ao invés de simples. Como você abriu no início as aspas duplas, ele considera essa antes do `5` um fechamento, e a depois do `5` um nova abertura.

#### Replace no ajax

Tente fazer um `replace`no momento do recebimento do texto, substituindo as aspas duplas pelas simples.

```
function SalvaSession(valor){
      $.post( "ajax_salva_session.php",
            {
                'texto' : valor.replace("\"", "\'")  //valor recebe o html do editor de texto
           },
           function (data) {
           }
      );
 }
```

Comment: humm, acho q esse é outro também, deve ser por isso que ta aparecendo esse undefined variable: _SESSION... junto do texto vindo do editor

Comment: eu coloquei o código $texto = str_replace('"', "\"", $texto);

Comment: O erro continua, agora to em duvida se o erro é realmente por essas duas coisas ou por alguma outra coisa

Comment: puts, mas não vai dar pra alterar dinamicamente? porque  o html gerado é gerado pelo editor de texto, e não por mim...

Comment: Isso que eu estava pensando, imagino que daria na hora da captura, no ajax, no caso. Vou editar a resposta com uma possível maneira, tente e veja se dá certo.

Comment: Editei, se não servir imagino não saiba mais o como te ajudar, mas espera que tenha servido de algo até o momento..

Comment: <textarea id="paragrafo" name="paragrafo" onblur=="SalvaSession($('#paragrafo').Editor('getText'));"></textarea>

Comment: o editor q to usando é o line control editor, o link dele é esse github.com/suyati/line-control/blob/master/README.md  foi aqui q eu achei mais informações a respeito dele

Comment: consegui remover a quebra de linha enfim! obrigado por toda a ajud, suas dicas ajudaram, acho que o problema maior foi eu n ter declarado o session_start() no inicio e ele ter salvo no session o codigo errado, e daí dava erro o tempo todo, agora mudei o que está armazenado no session e consegui resolver pelo menos isso, agr preciso ver como o editor interpreta o codigo, porque ta setando o texto html literal e não aparece ele todo formatado, mas muito obrigado de qq forma @SamirBraga

Comment: @AlexandreMartinsMontebelo, fico feliz em saber que teve avanços... Boa sorte com a continuação dos problemas, espero que os resolva também :) .

Answer (score 2):

```
$logradouro = htmlentities($logradouro, null, 'utf-8');
$logradouro = str_replace("&nbsp;"," ",$logradouro);
$logradouro = str_replace("\n", "", $logradouro);
$logradouro = str_replace("\r", "", $logradouro);
$logradouro = preg_replace('/\s/',' ',$logradouro);
```